# Upload file from Android to a server (without PHP)

Tags: android, .net, upload, io

Is there any way we can upload file from android phone to a server without using PHP

all the examples I found were with PHP

is there any other way?

Comment: do you heard about FTP ??

Comment: yes I heard about FTP, are you here to be sarcastic or to help?! I want via http

Comment: why you dot mention about this in your question ?? you can get a lot ways in http also with out PHP and with c# or java

Comment: Sorry I am not as expert as you are, thats why I post here to get some help in that area that I do not know much.

Comment: it is ok look the below link and do ask some c# expert to write service http://www.codicode.com/art/upload_files_from_android_to_a_w.aspx

Comment: I had to use FTP in the end. thanks

Comment: that is why i said first, we had come across some thing like this and atlast we found FTP is the essay way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use FTP to do this. could not find answer for http